# Add manufacturer name for a windows application using click once

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a windows application deployed in Click Once. 
The application is added into startup items. 
Now when i check msconfig, i could see 'Manufacturer' field is given 'Unknown'. I have provided enough information in its assembly. How could i do it , either programmatically or manually?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce does not use the assembly information. Open your Windows Application in visual studio, go to the project properties, go to the Publish tab. Click on Options. The Publisher Name is what is used for the group on the start menu. Suite Name is a sub-group under the group, and Product Name is the name of the actual start shortcut.